# Nativescript-vue: 'admob createBanner error: Error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, vue.js, admob, nativescript, nativescript-vue

i'm using the **nativescript-admob** plugin with **nativescript-vue**. 
when i run i get this error :

**JS: 'admob createBanner error: Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method \'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()\' on a null object reference'**

my code:

```js
 created(){
            return this.banner();
        },
methods: {
            banner(){
                 admob.createBanner({
                    testing: true,
                    size: admob.AD_SIZE.SMART_BANNER, 
                    androidBannerId: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111", // add your own
                    margins: {
                        //top: 10
                        bottom: 50
                    },
                    keywords: ["keyword1", "keyword2"] // add keywords for ad targeting
                }).then(
                    function() {
                        console.log("admob createBanner done");
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        console.log("admob createBanner error: " + error);
                    }
                )
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by putting **this.banner();** in the click of a button in my app instead of **created()**